# How to monitor free running output and send keystroke in python to terminate it based on output pattern

Tags: python-3.x, subprocess, pipe, signals, keystroke

Example input script

```
import time
for i in range(5):
    print("LOADING " + str(i))
    time.sleep(1)
for i in range(10):
    print("RUNNING " + str(i))
    time.sleep(1)
```

Need a way to run launch the script, preferably python 3 subprocess and monitor and print the output continuously and terminate it as soon as it starts printing 'RUNNING', similar to sending CTRL+C in terminal

There are similar solution but nothing seems to be serving this purpose
[How to terminate a python subprocess launched with shell=True](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4789837/how-to-terminate-a-python-subprocess-launched-with-shell-true)

Answer (score 0):

If you are fine with using `pwntools` (https://github.com/Gallopsled/pwntools), you could start with the following code:

```
# pip install pwntools

from pwn import *

# don't print pwntool stuff
context.log_level = 'error'

# start process
proc = process(["python3", "child.py"])

# read line-by-line and print line (until 'RUNNING' is printed)
while not (line := proc.readline()).startswith(b"RUNNING"):
    print(line.decode(), end = "")

# kill process
proc.kill()

# this will be printed (parent is not killed)
print("Parent still running")
```

This code reads the input line-by-line.
If you need to terminate before the full line is read, try `proc.read(1)` to read a single byte.

Comment: Thanks, looks like the solution is working, couldn't upvote